# java.time.LocalDateTime being persisted as tinyblob rather than a TemporalType in JPA with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jodatime, java-time

I'm trying to use `java.time.LocalDateTime` but apparently `Hibernate 4.3.5` (I am using JPA) doesn't support `LocalDateTime` as a `TemporalType` ([Feature Request](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844)).

Is there any workaround to persist `java.time.LocalDateTime` as a `TemporalType` in `Hibernate`?

And what could be my best alternative(`java.util.Date` or `jodatime`) such that I can easily migrate to `LocalDateTime` after it is supported?

Answer (score 0):

If object creation isn't a problem for you (i.e. GC), joda datetime package is almostly a 1-1 match with `java.time` package, except that joda package doesn't provide a way to translate the joda date/datetime into milliseconds since epoch while `java.time` supports it by `Instant` class.

Sorry not expert in Hibernate so cannot answer your converting question - but suppose you could transfer into some helper class to facilitate persisting?

Answer (score 0):

You may find the [user type](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html) project useful for persisting JSR-310 classes in Hibernate. If it doesn't work out of the box, the source code should give you a clue on implementing the relevant Hibernate plugin points.